# My contact form is not sending emails

Tags: php, jquery, html

The contact form at the bottom of this page http://nmfnebbs.preview.infomaniak.website/
is not working, when I fill all the fields and I click on the button to send, the error message is displayed and nothing is sent to my Email.
Here is the script for the contact form:

```
  var submitContact = $('#submit_contact'),
    message = $('#msg');

submitContact.on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'contact.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: $('#contact-form').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {

            if(data.info !== 'error'){
                $this.parents('form').find('input[type=text],textarea,select').filter(':visible').val('');
                message.hide().removeClass('success').removeClass('error').addClass('success').html(data.msg).fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
            } else {
                message.hide().removeClass('success').removeClass('error').addClass('error').html(data.msg).fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and here is the content of contact.php (except my email address)

```
/* ==========================  Define variables ========================== */

#Your e-mail address
define("__TO__", "my email address");

#Message subject
define("__SUBJECT__", "IT-vip.com.tn");

#Success message
define('__SUCCESS_MESSAGE__', "Votre message a bien été envoyé");

#Error message
define('__ERROR_MESSAGE__', "Erreur, Votre message n'a pas été envoyé");

#Messege when one or more fields are empty
define('__MESSAGE_EMPTY_FILDS__', "Veuillez remplir tous les champs");

/* ========================  End Define variables ======================== */

//Send mail function
function send_mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers){
    if(@mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'success', 'msg' => __SUCCESS_MESSAGE__));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => __ERROR_MESSAGE__));
    }
}

//Check e-mail validation
function check_email($email){
    if(!@eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

//Get post data
if(isset($_POST['name']) and isset($_POST['mail']) and isset($_POST['comment'])){
    $name    = $_POST['name'];
    $mail    = $_POST['mail'];
    $website  = $_POST['website'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];

    if($name == '') {
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Veuillez saisir votre nom"));
        exit();
    } else if($mail == '' or check_email($mail) == false){
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Veuillez saisir votre e-mail valide"));
        exit();
    } else if($comment == ''){
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Veuillez saisir votre message."));
        exit();
    } else {
        //Send Mail
        $to = __TO__;
        $subject = __SUBJECT__ . ' ' . $name;
        $message = '
        <html>
        <head>
          <title>Mail from '. $name .'</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <table style="width: 500px; font-family: arial; font-size: 14px;" border="1">
            <tr style="height: 32px;">
              <th align="right" style="width:150px; padding-right:5px;">Name:</th>
              <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px; line-height: 20px;">'. $name .'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 32px;">
              <th align="right" style="width:150px; padding-right:5px;">E-mail:</th>
              <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px; line-height: 20px;">'. $mail .'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 32px;">
              <th align="right" style="width:150px; padding-right:5px;">Website:</th>
              <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px; line-height: 20px;">'. $website .'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 32px;">
              <th align="right" style="width:150px; padding-right:5px;">Comment:</th>
              <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px; line-height: 20px;">'. $comment .'</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </body>
        </html>
        ';

        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: ' . $mail . "\r\n";

        send_mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => __MESSAGE_EMPTY_FILDS__));
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Error in console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` ...

Comment: have u added jquery plugin

Comment: there is no error in console try to change
if(@mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) to
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))

Comment: add this script to your <head> tag  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: <<<<<thanks all for your quick help, I had no error in the console, but I added jquery in the header, I applied Shibon's solution, but nothing changed

Comment: you'll have to check your server logs to see if there's any error logged. apache logs and mail logs. mail() is a bit of a black box though, it can be difficult to debug. Consider using a library like SwiftMailer which can talk directly to an SMTP server.

Comment: After checking server logs, there is no error related to the contact form or any script.

Comment: Try sending the email to a different email address. Because as such there is no error in the code. Or if you can, host the same form on some other server for trial.